# Welcome message not sent from v4 bot published to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

When published to Azure, my bot does not show a splash message when a new user opens webchat. It works as expected locally via the emulator.

I've replicated this with the "send welcome message to users" sample code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp. Again, this works as described locally using the emulator but when published to Azure, the various events are not fired as compared to the emulator.

All the other subsequent bot functions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging, I found a marginally related question / answer that mentioned to make sure to check the "Remove additional files at destination" which is not checked by default. This appears to have fixed my problem.

Comment: where is this option FTP?

Comment: It's part of the publishing options in Visual Studio.When you right click on a project and select publish, you get a Publish page in VS. Then click on Edit which brings up another window for adjusting your connection and select "Settings" on that page. Still more digging, it's hidden under "File Publish Options" which you have to expand.